# Extract text from Image with black background

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to extract white text from image using **pytesseract** in Python but i didn't manage to get a good result.

It shows me the zeros as "@", "a" and "e".

Here's the image :

[image: the image, not hosted elsewhere]

Here's the sample Code i'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

def preprocess_finale(im):
    im= cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 55,60)
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, im = cv2.threshold(im, 240, 255, 1)
    return im

img = Image.open("Image.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

im = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
custom_config = r"--oem 3 --psm 4 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= '0123456789. '"
im=preprocess_finale(img)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng', config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

Here's the result:

> 900.265 NITa0e.234 LUX2566 Eulee

Is there any solution to get a better result ?

Comment: try `inv_img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. Here's the result: "900.265 NITaee.234 LUX2566 Eulee"

Comment: `tessedit_char_whitelist= 'NITLUXEV0123456789. '"`

Comment: that's some very very tiny text. tesseract is not made for that. -- did you look at the filtered output you send to tesseract? I wouldn't trust `bilateralFilter` to leave the text alone... that's liable to destroy the little data you have in the picture -- also, `cv.imread` needs a path string, not a numpy array. your code will throw errors. did you run that code? please review [mre] and also [ask]

Comment: @LMC thanks for the Hint but i don't know why it's always showing these "a" and "e".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for correcting that. When i wanted to make small code i made this Error. If tesseract is not made for that. Can you please suggest another method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use easy ocr with resized version of image.

```
import easyocr
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('Di0yp.png')
image  = cv2.resize(image,(780,600)) # 740,480 # 740,600
cv2.imwrite('resize.png',image)

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('resize.png')
for detection in result:
    print(detection)
```

the desired output is,

```
([[399, 313], [507, 313], [507, 333], [399, 333]], "'000, 265 NIT", 0.5332222214815537)
([[399, 333], [509, 333], [509, 351], [399, 351]], '000 , 834 LuX', 0.37962750554971325)
([[421, 351], [527, 351], [527, 371], [421, 371]], '0. 566 EV100', 0.440570646870379)
```

I think this might help you

Comment: I feel easyOCR is better than tesseract +1